# How to indicate function parameter function input type

Tags: typescript, input, types, parameters, parameter-passing

I am new to typescript.
I have a function that takes a function as an input parameter. This input parameter function has number input value.

```
preloadResources(informLoadPct: Function)
{
  let pct = 100;
  informLoadPct(pct);

}
```

I call this function like this

```
preloadResources((loadedPercentage: number) => {
  console.log(loadedPercentage);
});
```

as you can see the function parameter is a function that has number input type. Is there a way to define that also?

instead of "**informLoadPct: Function**" can we provide more information about this function?

Comment: change `Function` to `(arg: number) => void`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can. My prefered way is as follows:

```
type NumberLogger = (n: number) => void;

function preloadResources(informLoadPct: NumberLogger )
{
  let pct = 100;
  informLoadPct(pct);

}
```

If you ever need to pass this inside an object, you can do the same thing.

```
type NumberLogger = (n: number) => void;

type NumberLoggerProps = {
    logger: NumberLogger;
}

// or

type NumberLoggerProps = {
    logger: (n: number) => void;
}

// or

type NumberLoggerProps = {
    logger(n: number): void;
}
```

See more in the [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html).